# Set production mode magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cli, production-mode, shell

I want to switch to production mode but I can not find information about the exact commands that I have to use. I know that I must use this command:

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

But, do I need to make some change of permission for the folders? Do I need to execute some more command before or after using the command to change to production mode?

**UPDATE**

These are the commands I use to give permissions to my Magento files and folders:

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chown -R :www-data .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: Directly run this command. No need to change any permission or other command.

Comment: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation

Comment: The folder permissions that I use are the ones that I have added in my question. Are those correct for developer mode and production mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this command to set production mode:

> bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

**Note:** If you are going to switch from Developer to Production mode two actions must first be taken.

> 1) Static Deploy (bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy)
>
> 2) Compilation (bin/magento setup:di:compile)

Comment: ok and what is the commands for do this?

Comment: @Despotars I have updated the answer.

Comment: The folder permissions that I use are the ones that I have added in my question. Are those correct for developer mode and production mode?

Comment: @Despotars Yes that's correct.

Comment: Being in production mode, if I need to install something, I must switch to development mode, right? Do I have to use some extra command? or should I just use this command?: bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Comment: Yes, first you have to switch any default or developer mode by using this command bin/magento deploy:mode:set default/developer after that you can install the any modules.

Comment: ok thank you very much! My last question, when should I switch to developer mode? just to install modules? Or also to add new products or categories?

Comment: You can add product/category in production mode but after adding any changes you must to run deploy command (bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy)

Answer (score 2):

You only need to run this command, to switch to production mode

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

In case, you get blank screen,
You should run

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

then

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

then

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

That's enough!

Comment: I don't think so we need upgrade, deploy and reindex in order to change mode alone, each of these have specific functionality in it. So it doesn't require mate

Comment: The folder permissions that I use are the ones that I have added in my question. Are those correct for developer mode and production mode?

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, yes you are right. it's only required if there is blank screen after production mode set. i have to run these commands after i switch to production mode whenever i get blank white screen

Comment: @Khushbu.... yes it worked for me