# Switching to developer mode not working in M2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Good day everyone, We have recently migrated our site from one server to another server and configured Varnish and Redis. Now when I try to switch my magento mode from default to developer using `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` my layout is breaking up and I am not able to see any products. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding this maybe a screenshot in to what the exact issue is you are seeing. this may be down to you having sign static content enabled on static content enabled to check this run the following "bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 0" minus quotes once done if you flush cache this should load the page correctly

Comment: you can check this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277941/set-production-mode-magento-2-3/277949#277949 may be it help you!

Comment: Hi @FaisalSheikh, thanks for the answer but I do not want to enable the production mode.

Comment: Hi @DavaGordon, thanks for taking the time and answering, the issue is I am able to see the headings but the products slider is not showing up. Will try to run the command you provided :)

Comment: @shivam if you view the page source you will see in your urls to css files and js files it will contain version-###### this will let you know if static sign is turned on or not this can have an impact :)

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/9hxy9tt/site-error.png
@DavaGordon The entire layout is broken.

Comment: @shivam does the new server have redis enabled? if so possible you may need to run "redis-cli flushall"

Comment: @DavaGordon Tried redis-cli flushall, still the same.

Comment: @shivam what version of magento 2 are you running also what PHP version?

Comment: Magento 2.3.5 and php 7.3.27-9

Comment: another thing to check is your permissions can you try running "find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento" minus quotes. to see if is a permission based issue :)

Comment: Another thing is try and rerun bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer and then look in the system.log and the exception.log even server error logs to see if there were any issues logged at the time of performing the action. i know there have been a few issues in the past with magento and php 7.3

Comment: @DavaGordon 
main.CRITICAL: Requested path '_cache/merged/fonts_7dca6606d35b56f4e216e41c8d398fe8.min.css' is wrong. [] [] there are few lines with this :(

Comment: @shivam thats a big help :) if you run "bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 0" and "bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 0" and "bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 0" then flush cache and let me know the result :)

Comment: Even this did not help ;(

Comment: @shivam are there any other errors in the logs now? as that should clear out any merge errors. also do you have a link by any chance

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/JvjWyNF/var-log-debug.png

Comment: If you disabled mergeing of CSS and JS that error should be gone. if you look at your console can you see any issues. also are you running apache or ngnix

Comment: I am using Apache.

Answer (score 0):

At First delete the contents of the `generated/code` and `generated/metadata` directories

```
rm -rf <magento_root>/generated/metadata/* <magento_root>/generated/code/*
```

then Set the mode:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

`Enabled developer mode.` will be show.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time but this is not working as well.

Comment: what is the error after run command

Comment: There is no error, it just did not fix the broken layout.